# Balancing Power in a Simple Circuit When not all Wattages are known

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

I am having trouble solving the following problem. I understand that the net power should be 0, but it seems that there is no way to determine the power of elements 2, 3, and 5. How would one go about solving such a problem?

Find Ix in the circuit when P1 = -18.0W, and P4 = 13.0W, using the passive sign convention and power balance. The rectangles containing numbers represent arbitrary circuit elements.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know P1 and you know the current in P1 so you can calculate the bus voltage trivially.

Once you have the voltage then power levels for 2,5 are trivially derived because you know the currents.

Do the (signed appropriately) addition and you get the power in 3 + 6, from which you can get Ix (and if desired) the power P3 alone.